# Font awesome Icons not showing when used within TCPDF library?

Tags: laravel, font-awesome, tcpdf

I'm currently creating html template designs in `Laravel` which are outputted as PDF documents and would like to use the font-awesome icons within the PDF documents.

I have tried the following syntax:

```
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('fontawesome-webfont.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96); 
$bod = '<span style="font-family:FontAwesome;font-size: 2em;">&#xf036;</span>';
PDF::writeHTML(nl2br($bod), true, false, true, false);
```

However when viewing the PDF document regardless of which hex code is used to display the icon its just displays a question mark. How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: $bod = '<span style="font-family:FontAwesome;font-size: 2em;">&#xf036;</span>' *

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inline styles, try setting the font with [setFont()](https://tcpdf.org/docs/source_docs/classTCPDF/#afd56e360c43553830d543323e81bc045) before displaying `$bod`:

```
PDF::setFont('FontAwesome','',20);
PDF::writeHTML(nl2br($bod), true, false, true, false);
```

Possible, you will need to open the font definition file, generated by your `addTTFFont` and check it for the proper font name to use with `setFont()` (in my example, i assumed it to be *FontAwesome*).

Also, pay attention to the difference between `addTTFFont` and `addFont` methods. You only need to call `addTTFFont` once — it will create needed files from your TTF. After that, you can add them with `addFont` method, using proper name (see the generated font definition file for it).